# Breeze.net - slow performance after updating to .net 6

Tags: breeze, breeze-sharp

We are updating our project from .net framework 4.7 to .net core 6, but are experiencing some performance issues. Everything was working fine in .net framework 4.7, but now requests are taking a very long time and some even get a timeout exception. Calling the metadata goes very fast (19 ms). Does someone knows what the problem could be? Should we disable something, like LazyLoading, on our DbContext?

This payload is now taking 4,5 seconds than our .net framework version (315 ms)

```js
{"where":{"Deleted":false,"or":[{"OrderStatus":"Processing","OrderNumber":{"contains":"189670"}},{"OrderStatus":"OnHold","Reference":{"contains":"189670"}},{"Customer.Name":{"contains":"189670"}}]},"orderBy":["Id desc"],"expand":["Customer"],"take":10,"inlineCount":true}:
```

[image: this is a screenshot taken from dotTrace]

Comment: Look at SQL Server's execution-plan for your queries - my guess is you're getting tripped-up by Parameter Sniffing - also, it looks like you aren't using async methods when you should be: you should use `await query,ToListaAsync(...)` with `IQueryable<T>` (and `DbSet<T>`), and `await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` to save - if you're using `SqlCommand`/`SqlDataReader` directly then you should use `await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(...)` and `await rdr.ReadAsync(...)`.

Comment: Aside from the performance, are your query results the same?

Comment: @SteveSchmitt yes. I did not change anything the request is the same. Only changed the Breeze packages and followed  the instructions. Instead of working with odata now using json...

Comment: Ok thanks @Nesse.  I just wanted to make sure that you weren't returning 10x the rows because filtering wasn't working, or something like that.

Comment: @Dai be careful when changing to async if you've got blob data, because of this issue:
https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/593

Comment: @SteveSchmitt Thanks for the tip - I didn't know about this issue - and _damn_ it looks bad.

Comment: @Nesse can you use SQL Server Profiler (part of SQL Server Management Studio) to compare the generated queries between .NET 4.7 and 6?

Comment: @SteveSchmitt I did some profiling and It looks like my breeze server is translating the request to a badly formed SQL command.

.NET Framework 4 + breeze EF6 (2.0.1) => returns 228 rows (1,2 seconds)
.NET 7 + breeze EFCore (7.1.0) => returns 466560 rows (49,3 seconds)

Comment: .NET Framework 4  => 

`$filter=(Id eq 51798) or (Id eq 51799) or (Id eq 51800) or (Id eq 51801) or (Id eq 51802) or (Id eq 51803)&$expand=ProductPictures,ProductCategories,ProductManufacturers,ProductSpecificationAttributes,ProductTierPrices,StockItems/StockUnits/WarehouseLocation,RelatedProducts,CrossSellProducts,BundledProducts,GroupedProducts,ProductPurchasePrices,ProductGroup,ProductTranslations`

Comment: .NET 7 =>

`{"where":{"or":[{"Id":51798},{"Id":51799},{"Id":51800},{"Id":51801},{"Id":51802},{"Id":51803}]},"expand":["ProductPictures","ProductCategories","ProductManufacturers","ProductSpecificationAttributes","ProductTierPrices","StockItems.StockUnits.WarehouseLocation","RelatedProducts","CrossSellProducts","BundledProducts","GroupedProducts","ProductPurchasePrices","ProductGroup","ProductTranslations"],"inlineCount":true}`

Comment: You are getting 2000x the rows in your .NET 7 query.  It seems like the `where` clause is not being applied.  Do you have the `[BreezeQueryFilter]` attribute on your controller?

Comment: @SteveSchmitt Thx for your feedback. the `[BreezeQueryFilter]` is applied to our controller. I've looked at the SQL commands and I see that the command generated by the .NET 4 version is using `UNION` and the .NET 7 version only `LEFT JOIN` ...

Comment: @SteveSchmitt Would you know if we are doing something wrong?

Comment: Please update your question to include code from your controller method and the resulting SQL.